# Can we use SQL Server 2012 Web (Azure) to host database for windows application and to run SSIS/SQL jobs?

Tags: sql-server-2012, azure-sql-database, hosted

Can we use SQL Server 2012 Web (Azure) to host database for  windows application and give the windows application a connection string to this db ? Or is it only used with web application?

Can we also run SSIS/SQL jobs on this web version of SQL Server?
http://databases.about.com/od/sqlserver/a/sql_server_2012_licensing.htm This article mentions that SQL Server 2012 Web is a specialized version of SQL Server for use in web hosting environments.

Please advice.